# Swift Reload CurrentView

Tags: swift

I am trying to reload the current view controller.

All the examples I can find, are for either pull to refresh or how to reload a tableview.

I have used SwiftSpinner (https://github.com/icanzilb/SwiftSpinner) in my project. When I use:

```
SwiftSpinner.show("Please connect to the internet, and try again").addTapHandler({
 SwiftSpinner.hide({
      print("Closed")
 })
}, subtitle: "Tap to try again..")
```

When the user taps the view to close the spinner, I get Closed in the Console.

I have tried changing that print to:

```
self.loadView()
```

However this does not do anything.

How do I get the view to reload?

Comment: Also, Why the downvote? The question is clear and I have tried something which didnt work and reported the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot 'reload' the viewController (Please correct me if I am wrong).

What are you trying to reload? Is it something specifically? It looks like you are checking for internet connection, right?

What I reccommend is, in your **viewDidLoad** take everything out and put it in a function, for example **stuffToLoad()**

Then, call that function in your ViewDidLoad. Run the app, does everything still work the way it is supposed to? If so that means you can now use:

```
SwiftSpinner.show("Please connect to the internet, and try again").addTapHandler({
   SwiftSpinner.hide({
      self.stuffToLoad()
 })
}, subtitle: "Tap to try again..")
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked perfectly. :)